# Rounding a sum in Python using round()

Tags: python

I am very new to Python2.7 (like Day 1 new), and I am trying to write a simple Mils to Degrees conversion program as a learning exercise. The program asks the user to choose to convert from degrees to mils or vice versa, then asks for a value. It divides or multiplies accordingly and prints the converted answer. Here's where the problem arises. The converted answer should not be returned as an exact floating point number. For instance- if the user inputs 6400 mils I want the program to return 360 degrees (1 degree = 17.78 mils), not 359.955 degrees. My (limited) understanding of the round function is that it accepts a float and level of precision but does not accept variables. How do I pass the sum to round()?

Your input is greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
import math

def menu():

    print ""
    print " Mils / Degrees Conversion Calculator"
    print "-" * 38
    print ""
    print "Options: "
    print "1. Degrees to Mils"
    print ""
    print "2. Mils to Degrees"
    print ""
    print "3. Quit"
    print "-" * 20
    print""
    return input ("Choose your option: ")
    print ""

#This function contains my attempt at rounding the sum and returns errors
def m2d(a):
    print "Enter azimuth in mils (ex. 6400)"
    b = 17.78
    c = a / b
    print a, " mils = ", c, "degrees"
    round(c[])

#This function works as intended but does not include round()
def d2m(b):
    print "Enter azimuth in degrees (ex. 90)"
    a = 17.78
    print b, " degrees = ", b * a, "mils"


loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
       d2m(input("Degrees: "))

    elif choice == 2:
        m2d(input("Mils: "))

    elif choice == 3:
        loop = 0
```

Comment: You would pass the float as a variable `round(c, 2)` would round `c` to two decimal places. *added as an answer instead*

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I misinterpreted the documentation and actually put the brackets in the argument. Getting rid of those stopped the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> round(359.955)
360.0

def m2d(a):
    print "Enter azimuth in mils (ex. 6400)"
    b = 17.78
    c = round((a / b),0) #This would round the value to zero decimal places.
    print a, " mils = ", c, "degrees"

>>> m2d(6400)
Enter azimuth in mils (ex. 6400)
6400  mils =  360.0 degrees
```

For more information on round() see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

If you want no decimal places when you print you can place replace `c` with `int(c)`.

Also when your say print var1,var2 it automatically puts a space between the two. You might want to try:

```
    print a, "mils =", c, "degrees"
```

Comment: Hi @Betastate If you are happy with Ophion's answer it is good etiquette to mark this question as answered. You can do that by ticking the tick mark next to the question.

Comment: My apologies, @NickPerkins. I'm also new to this sort of forum. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You would pass the float as a variable.

```
round(c, 2)
```

would round c to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

For Day 1 knowledge, you're understanding the concept of python quite well.  Now, there is some things in the code that could be changed to make some inputs easier, but it's very simple to modify:

```
c = a / b
c = round(c)
```

As it seems you're rounding the variable without changing the variable itself, that what's causing the problem.

Comment: "For Day 1 knowledge, you're understanding the concept of python quite well."

THanks, Hairr. I do have a little experience with C. That knowledge is a definite benefit in understanding the basic formatting, syntax, etc. It's not completely analogous but it gives me something to work with. They weren't kidding when they said Python is significantly easier than languages in the C family.